# Databricks Delta Live Streaming duplicates every record

Tags: azure-databricks, delta-live-tables

I have created an ADF pipeline that queries an Azure SQL Database and loads a parquet file into my ADLS gen 2 storage.  I have downloaded a parquet viewer and can see that there are 449768 records in the parquet file, which matches the count from the SQL Server table.

I have created a databricks streaming table with the following code:

```sql
CREATE OR REFRESH STREAMING LIVE TABLE Asset 
AS
SELECT * FROM cloud_files("abfss://datalake@storageaccountname.dfs.core.windows.net/loading/Settlement/dbo/Asset", 
"parquet", map("cloudFiles.inferColumnTypes", "true"))
```

There is only 1 file in the loading folder but there are duplicates in my databricks hive schema after running the Delta Live Table job.

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Thanks,
Leslie

Comment: https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta-live-tables/sql-ref.html#change-data-capture-with-sql-in-delta-live-tables

Comment: thanks, I am not trying to track changes at this point, I am doing the initial load.  I have one extract file and am creating the table.  I have dropped the table and schema from the hive catalog and the folder in the datalake.

Comment: Where do you store the resulting data?